# Number of Non-negative solutions to an equation

Tags: combinatorics

$$X+Y+Z=N_{3}\; ,X\leq Y\leq Z$$
$$X,Y,Z,N_{3}\in \mathbb{N}\cup \left \{ 0 \right \}$$
How many solutions will be there to this equation?

Can I also get the general solution of 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}=N_{n}\; ,X_{1}\leq X_{2}\leq X_{3}\leq...\leq X_{n-1} \leq X_{n}$$
$$X_{1},X_{2},X_{3},...,X_{n-1},X_{n},N_{n}\in \mathbb{N}\cup \left \{ 0 \right \}$$
?

I hope the solutions can be represented in floor functions.

EDIT

The number of solutions of the first equation without restrictions is 
$$C_{2}^{N_{3}+2}$$
 I think that I should think of 4 cases
$$X<Y<Z,X=Y<Z,X<Y=Z,X=Y=Z$$,
and obviously,when $$X=Y=Z$$, the number of the solutions is 1 if

$$3∣N_{3}$$

and 0 otherwise.

Comment: The number of solutions of the first equation without restrictions is C(N+2,2).
I think that I should think of 4 cases- X<Y<Z, X=Y<Z, X<Y=Z, and X=Y=Z.

Comment: Please include this in an edit before your question is closed as off topic.

Comment: Consider the case of $N_3 = 2$, then there are two solutions, $(0,0,2)$ and $(0,1,1)$, not $0$ as you claim.

Comment: 0 if X=Y=Z.
"when X=Y=Z, the number of the solutions is 1 if 3∣N3 and 0 otherwise."